# set device name for AS400 in jtopen

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, jt400

I'm trying to connect to AS400 machine using jt400. When I first tried to connect to AS400 using tn5250, there is a column asking for device name.
Example as below:

[image: tn5250 image]

When I try to write a java code to set connection to AS400, I couldn't find anything on how to set the device name. Is there any way for me to pass a device name when trying to connect to AS400?

I'm using jt400 version 8.5

Comment: In general, "Device Name" would refer to a telnet **terminal device**. But you aren't doing telnet; you're doing jt400 connections to other server functions that have no associated "device". No "device" is needed for jt400 connections.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer was given in the comments by user2338816.

JT400 uses a different means to connect. Please look into the javadocs for the class `com.ibm.as400.access.AS400`.